# How can I fit an excel file with 7303 rows into word properly and with 3 tables on each page?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an .xlsx file. There are 7303 columnar data in this excel file. When I copy and paste all of them to word, an extremely ugly image appears, and I get a 200-page print. I would like to minimize this and fit it into 3 tables on each page. How can I do that?

Example xlsx data like this:

[image: A excel file shows sample data]

The word file.

[image: A word file shows sample data]

Comment: 7303 rows or 7303 columns, or both? Did you try the scaling option when you print?

Comment: 7303 colums 2 rows. I did it...

Comment: `7303 colums 2 rows.` `3 tables on each page` without samples and illustrations how can we imagine what resulting image of your hope?

Comment: @OscarSun i added some pictures to explain my question properly. Thanks.

Comment: the image you showed is not `7303 colums 2 rows.` should be 7303 rows 2 columns.

Comment: @OscarSun yea my bad. so, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Can you accept this kind of layout(multi-columns(3-columns)) on every page of your table?

[image]
[image]

**If you can**, just use the ribbon to set this after you paste the table from your Excel file. Or can apply by a VBA procedure. Sorry, I have the traditional Chinese version only.

**Plan B : If you just want what you showed above**, then you mean **just only one table** in a Word document and it has 6 columns and you want to fill them from left to right according to your Excel file data... Isn't it? Then only running VBA code can make it I thought. And I'll try later. Waiting for your response.

### Plan B

Well, that's probably what this is.

And run this code from your Excel file to check out.

```vb
Sub How_can_I_fit_an_excel_file_with_7303_rows_into_word_properly_and_with_3_tables_on_each_page()

'    Dim wd As Word.Application, d As Word.Document, tb As Word.Table,pn As Long, cIndex As Long, rowsCountInPage As Integer, rPage As Integer, columnTimes As Byte, columnTimesCount As Byte, pageLastCell As Word.cell, pageLastRowIndex As Long, newTableRng As Word.Range, newTableRowsCount As Integer
    Dim wd As Object, d As Object, tb As Object, pn As Long, cIndex As Long, rowsCountInPage As Integer, rPage As Integer, columnTimes As Byte, columnTimesCount As Byte, pageLastCell As Object, pageLastRowIndex As Long, titleStrArr() As String, newTableRng As Object, newTableRowsCount As Integer
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet, rowCount As Long, r As Long, cellCount As Long
'    Dim ws As Object, rowCount As Long, r As Long, cellCount As Long, ex As Object
    Dim cellRemainCount As Integer, cellTableRemainCount As Integer
    Dim columnCountExcel  As Integer, refillRowsCount As Integer
    Dim i As Long 'a general indexer for loop use
    
    Rem Excel file's columns count. Merged cells are not applicable!
    columnCountExcel = 2
    Rem set the title string value
    ReDim titleStrArr(columnCountExcel - 1) As String
    
    Rem How many Excel columns as one in Word table
    columnTimesCount = 3
    
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    rowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set wd = VBA.CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    Rem can be false to up the efficiency
    wd.Visible = True 'just for test to watch
    'Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False'up the efficiency if you want
        
    Set d = wd.Documents.Add
    Set tb = d.Tables.Add(d.Range.Characters(1), 10, columnCountExcel * columnTimesCount) ' just insert 10 rows first
    tb.Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = False
    With tb.Borders
        .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    End With
    pn = 1
    'create the table to fit into first page
    GoSub make_the_table_fill_up_the_page
    
    Rem Get the count of cells which will be managed
    'Set rng = Range(ws.UsedRange.Cells(1), ws.UsedRange.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Cells.Count))
    'cellCount = rng.Cells.Count
    cellCount = ws.UsedRange.Cells.Count
    cIndex = 1: r = 1: rPage = 1
        
    Do While cIndex < cellCount
        
        If cIndex Mod columnCountExcel = 0 Then
            r = r + 1
            rPage = rPage + 1
        End If
        If rowsCountInPage < rPage Then
            columnTimes = columnTimes + 1
            If pn > 1 Then
                rPage = 1
                
            'if the first page , has title
            Else
                rPage = 2
                Rem field name row , fill up
                    'If tb.cell(1, columnTimes * columnCountExcel + 1).Range.Text <> tb.cell(1, 1).Range.Text Then
                If titleStrArr(0) = "" Then
                    For i = 0 To columnCountExcel - 1
                        titleStrArr(i) = Left(tb.cell(1, i + 1).Range.Text, Len(tb.cell(1, i + 1).Range.Text) - 2)
'                        titleStrArr(0) = Left(tb.cell(1, 1).Range.Text, Len(tb.cell(1, 1).Range.Text) - 2)
'                        titleStrArr(1) = Left(tb.cell(1, 2).Range.Text, Len(tb.cell(1, 2).Range.Text) - 2)
                    Next i
                End If
                If VBA.InStr(tb.cell(1, columnTimes * columnCountExcel + 1).Range.Text, titleStrArr(0)) = 0 Then
                    For i = 0 To columnCountExcel - 1
                        tb.cell(1, columnTimes * columnCountExcel + 1 + i).Range.Text = titleStrArr(i)
                    Next i
'                    tb.cell(1, columnTimes * columnCountExcel + 1).Range.Text = titleStrArr(0)
'                    tb.cell(1, columnTimes * columnCountExcel + columnCountExcel).Range.Text = titleStrArr(1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
'''        If columnTimes + 1 > columnTimesCount Then
'''            columnTimes = 0
'''        End If
        
        Rem fill the cells from Excel data
        For i = 0 To columnCountExcel - 1
            tb.cell(rPage + pageLastRowIndex, columnTimes * columnCountExcel + 1 + i).Range.Text = ws.Cells(r, i + 1).Value
        Next i
'        tb.cell(rPage + pageLastRowIndex, columnTimes * columnCountExcel + 1).Range.Text = ws.Cells(r, 1).Value
'        tb.cell(rPage + pageLastRowIndex, columnTimes * columnCountExcel + columnCountExcel).Range.Text = ws.Cells(r, columnCountExcel).Value
        
        If cIndex = 1 Then
            cIndex = cIndex + (columnCountExcel - 1) 'cIndex start at 1, so
        Else
            cIndex = cIndex + columnCountExcel
        End If
        
        

'    Rem   just for Check
'        If ws.Cells(r, columnCountExcel).Value = "101010292" Then '"101010301" Then '"101010312" Then '"101010292" Then
'            Shell "W:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe C:\Windows\Media\ring03.wav"
'            Stop
'            'If cRng.Row > rowCount Then Exit For
'        End If
        
        
        
        While tb.Range.Cells(tb.Range.Cells.Count).Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > pn
'            Stop ' check, because the content of cells may be expand the table
            Rem If your content of cells will expand the table to over one page, this is necessary to be implemented
            
            'reset rowsCountInPage
            'Check before deleting rows beyond this page.
            If VBA.Len(tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Cells(1).Range.Text) > 2 Then ' if already input
                Select Case columnTimes
                    Case 0
                        'r = r - 1 'for restore to the correct cell after delete
                        refillRowsCount = 1
                        'r = r - refillRowsCount ' mearged after `r = r - refillRowsCount 'for restore to the correct cell after delete`
                                                'cIndex = cIndex - columnCountExcel
                                                'cIndex = cIndex - refillRowsCount * columnCountExcel

                    Case Else
                        Rem Calculate the number of affected cells
                        If pn = 1 Then
                            rPage = rPage - 1 'the first row is tiltle
                            refillRowsCount = rowsCountInPage - 1 'just no more anothor variable
                        Else
                            refillRowsCount = rowsCountInPage
                        End If
                        '"1" is First set of cells in this will be deleted row,"2" is the current set of columns and the first set of columns
                        'refillRowsCount = (1) + (refillRowsCount * (columnTimesCount - columnTimes - 2)) + (rPage)
                        refillRowsCount = (1) + (refillRowsCount * (columnTimes - 1)) + (rPage)
                        rPage = rowsCountInPage '+ 1 'for the line `If rowsCountInPage < rPage Then`, to recount
                                                '+1 no need, cause after already `rowsCountInPage = rowsCountInPage - 1`
                        
                        columnTimes = 0 ' if beyond the page, must from first colunm refill 'columnTimes - 1 'for `columnTimes = columnTimes + 1`
                End Select
                        
                cIndex = cIndex - refillRowsCount * columnCountExcel
                r = r - refillRowsCount 'for restore to the correct cell after delete
                
            End If
            rowsCountInPage = rowsCountInPage - 1
            tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Delete
        Wend
        
        
        'When the last cell in a page is filled up
        If VBA.Len(tb.Range.Cells(tb.Range.Cells.Count).Range.Text) > 2 Then ' blank cell is made up by chr(13) & chr(7)
            If cIndex < cellCount Then
                Set pageLastCell = tb.Range.Cells(tb.Range.Cells.Count)
                pageLastRowIndex = pageLastCell.RowIndex
                columnTimes = 0: rPage = 0
                pn = pn + 1
                GoSub make_the_table_fill_up_the_page:
            End If
        End If
        
    Loop

    'Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True' If you false this before then don't forget this!
    
    If wd.Visible = False Then wd.Visible = True
    wd.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
    wd.Activate
    
    
    Beep
'    Shell "W:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe C:\Windows\Media\ring03.wav" 'just for test
    Debug.Print tb.Range.Cells.Count
    
'    MsgBox "done!", vbInformation

    
    Exit Sub
    
make_the_table_fill_up_the_page:
        
        
        
        If pn > 1 Then
            Set newTableRng = d.Range(tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Range.Next.Start, tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Range.Next.End)
            'newTableRng.SetRange tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Range.Next.Start, tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Range.Next.End
            newTableRng.Tables.Add newTableRng, newTableRowsCount, tb.Columns.Count 'just to adjust the count of rows to fit to promote efficiency
            tb.Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = False
            With tb.Borders
                .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            End With

        Rem this may be more fast, however this has to taking up clipboard resources
'            Set newTableRng = d.Range(tb.cell(VBA.IIf(pageLastRowIndex - rowsCountInPage = 0, 1, pageLastRowIndex - rowsCountInPage + 1), 1).Range.Start, pageLastCell.Range.End)
'            newTableRng.Copy
'            newTableRng.SetRange tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Range.Next.Start, tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Range.Next.End
'            newTableRng.Paste
'            Rem can't use FormattedText to achieve above effect
''            d.Range(tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Range.Next.Start, tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Range.Next.End).FormattedText = newTableRng.FormattedText
'
'            'newTableRng.Select 'just for watch
'            newTableRng.Start = tb.cell(tb.Rows.Count - rowsCountInPage + 1, 1).Range.Start
'            newTableRng.End = tb.cell(tb.Rows.Count, tb.Columns.Count).Range.End
'            newTableRng.Delete 'clear the content of the new pasted table
        End If
        
        
        Do While tb.Range.Next.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) <= pn 'And VBA.Len(tb.Range.Cells(tb.Range.Cells.Count).Range.Text) = 2 ' blank cell is made up by chr(13) & chr(7)
            tb.Rows.Add
        Loop
        If rowsCountInPage = 0 Then
            rowsCountInPage = tb.Rows.Count
            newTableRowsCount = rowsCountInPage
        Else
            rowsCountInPage = tb.Rows.Count - pageLastRowIndex
        End If
        'the last remain cells
        'If Not cRng Is Nothing Then
        If tb.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > 1 Then
            Rem Clear excess rows
            cellRemainCount = (rowCount - r) * columnCountExcel
            If cellRemainCount Mod columnTimesCount = 0 Then
                While cellRemainCount < rowsCountInPage * columnTimesCount * columnCountExcel
                    
'                    rem just for check
'                    If VBA.Len(tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Cells(1).Range.Text) > 2 Then ' if already input
'                        Stop
'                    End If

                    rowsCountInPage = rowsCountInPage - 1
                    tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Delete
                Wend
            Else
                While cellRemainCount < (rowsCountInPage - 1) * columnTimesCount * columnCountExcel
                    
'                    rem just for check
'                    If VBA.Len(tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Cells(1).Range.Text) > 2 Then ' if already input
'                        Stop
'                    End If
                    
                    rowsCountInPage = rowsCountInPage - 1
                    tb.Rows(tb.Rows.Count).Delete
                Wend
            End If
        End If
    Return
End Sub
```

- **Before**:

[image]

- **After**:

[image]

Comment: I tried this way too. However, whenever I use this option, all my data overlaps.

Comment: @MauriceMoss I can't understand how `all my data overlaps` because I don't have that file to try. So let us try Plan B?  Using VBA to fill a 6-column table in a Word file according to the Excel data. Shall we?

Comment: yes, please. Please tell me some steps to do that.

Comment: @MauriceMoss I can't tell you in words, I'm only able to show you in code. Wait moments for me to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: I also sent you a message on your facebook account.

Comment: @MauriceMoss Have got and replied.

Comment: @MauriceMoss You can try my code now from your Excel file.

Comment: @MauriceMoss Thank you for accepting this answer. When you accepted it, it still had bugs, and I've debugged already and I haven't found any bugs so far, but if there are any, I'll update it and let you know. Please test it with the code I've just updated, if you are interested or need it. As for this mechanism, it can definitely be optimized I believe, cause I'm just trying to implement it as far as I can. At least it works as expected without errors.